# Origin Search Phrase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Does anyone know if there is a way to capture the search phrase used to get to your site?  Do the search engines forward that information in any header values?

I have looked through all of the `Request.ServerVariables` and have not been able to find anything to do with the origin of the user (other than `HTTP_REFERER`).

I can see some anonymous information in Google Analytics but I am wanting to bind this information to user records upon account creation.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - UrlReferrer is where you *would* have to look. But as google search (by default) runs via https it will not send any Url Referrer. So you are out of luck here - sorry (or maybe good for the users ;-) ).

If you get visited by http you could try some fancy approach like:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/127681/Get-search-key-word-from-the-referrer-url

Answer (score 0):

If the page before loading your page was the search engine, you can use [UrlReferrer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) to get it and then maybe parse it to get the values

```
Uri MyUrl = Request.UrlReferrer;
 Response.Write("Referrer URL Port: " + Server.HtmlEncode(MyUrl.Port.ToString()) + "<br>");
 Response.Write("Referrer URL Protocol: " + Server.HtmlEncode(MyUrl.Scheme) + "<br>");
```

Hope it helps